# Using map() and forEach in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to use `.map()` function to transform an object, I try to get all orders of my order's table, I have another table called `OrderProducts`,  in this table I have some products, each products have an `OrderId` and I'd like to get each orders with each products inside the order's object...

My code doesn't work (it works if I remove the `_.forEach` function):

```js
self.ecOrderDao.getAll().success( function(allOrders){
  _.forEach(allOrders, function(order) {
    self.ecOrderProductDao.getAllByOrder(order.id).success( function(orderProducts){
      async.map(orders, function(order, callback){
        order.products = orderProducts;
        callback(null, order);
      }, function(err, transformed){
        response.render('ecorder/_index', {allOrders: transformed});
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is corrected code;

```
self.ecOrderDao.getAll().success( function(allOrders){
      async.map(allOrders, 
      function(order, callback){
        self.ecOrderProductDao.getAllByOrder(order.id).success( function(orderProducts){
            order.products = orderProducts;
            callback(null, order);
        });
      }, 
      function(err, transformed){
        response.render('ecorder/_index', {allOrders: transformed});
      });
});
```